# Adding to a message queue if more important messages come in

Tags: java, concurrency

We need to send messages with highest priority first so we use a `PriorityQueue` for our purpose.

```
PriorityQueue<MessageData> queue = new PriorityQueue<MessageData>();
```

However, we also want our queue to behave like a sorted set as well. Therefore, we adapt the `PriorityQueue` to ignore insertions which repeat existing members.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PrioritySet<E> extends PriorityQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34658778L;

    public PrioritySet() {
        super();
    }

    public PrioritySet(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        super(initialCapacity, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        boolean isAdded = false;
        if(!super.contains(e)) {
            isAdded = super.offer(e);
        }
        return isAdded;
    }
}
```

Now our app specific implementation of the data structure.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MessagePrioritySet extends PrioritySet<MessageData> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34658779L;

    private int minPriorityNumber;

    public MessagePrioritySet() {
        super();
    }

    public MessagePrioritySet(int initialCapacity, Comparator<MessageData> comparator) {
        super(initialCapacity, comparator);
    }

    public synchronized int getMinPriorityNumber() {
        return minPriorityNumber;
    }

    public synchronized void setMinPriorityNumber(int minPriorityNumber) {
        this.minPriorityNumber = minPriorityNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean offer(MessageData notification) {
        boolean isAdded = super.offer(notification);
        if (notification.getPriority() < minPriorityNumber)
            minPriorityNumber = notification.getPriority();
        return isAdded;
    }

    public synchronized void reportSent(MessageData notification) {
        MessageData nextMessageData = peek();
        if (nextMessageData == null)
            minPriorityNumber = 0;
        else if (nextMessageData.getPriority() > notification.getPriority())
            minPriorityNumber = nextMessageData.getPriority();
    }
}
```

Here, we want the data structure to be aware of the minimum priority value of the messages so we declare an instance variable for that. The priority of the incoming message is checked and if this priority is lower than the stored value, the value stored is updated. The use of the class is required to report any sent messages. If no other member of the data structure has a priority as low as the one being removed, then the next element's priority becomes the stored priority.

Two threads share the implemented queue. One thread fetches data from the database and inserts them into the queue. The other reads the queue and sends the highest priority message with the lowest priority number. Because the queue sets the minimum priority value to 0 and the thread which fetches data from the database reads rows with priority value lower than or equal to the minimum value stored in the queue if the stored minimum value is not zero, we can be pretty sure that while the current messages in the queue are being sent, only the new messages which are more important than those already in the queue will be added to the queue.

We think that the operations in the while loops in the threads should be atomic and would thank anyone who could tell us how to make them atomic.

```
private void startMptSender() {
    sleepInterval = 1000;
    final MessagePrioritySet messagePrioritySet = new MessagePrioritySet();

    Runnable mptReader = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                List<MessageData> messageDataList;

                if (messagePrioritySet.getMinPriorityNumber() == 0)
                    messageDataList = messageDao.readSMSMpt();
                else
                    messageDataList = messageDao.readSMSMpt(messagePrioritySet.getMinPriorityNumber());

                for (MessageData messageData : messageDataList) {
                    messagePrioritySet.offer(messageData);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                }
            }
        }
    };

    executor.execute(mptReader);

    Runnable mptPusher = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (status) {
                if (messagePrioritySet.size() > 0) {

                    while (messagePrioritySet.size() != 0) {
                        MessageData noti = messagePrioritySet.remove();
                        mptSender.sendSms(noti);
                        messageDao.markNotificationAsRead(noti.getSyskey());
                        messagePrioritySet.reportSent(noti);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    executor.execute(mptPusher);
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: surprisingly enough, review requests for (potentially) working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com. Then: I suggest to you try to write **shorter** sentences. Like the basic subject verb object thing. I have difficulties to grasp what you try to tell us; and that is mainly because you keep adding content to your sentences here and there, making it really hard to grasp what was going.

Comment: @GhostCat so is there a way to move this question to code review?

Comment: You still have a question here, on which I am currently answering. So I would suggest your question to remove the "review" part  ... and put up another request on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you mean with **atomic** translates to: you want that each thread is doing **all** of its work for one iteration **without** being interrupted by the other thread.

In other words: you have (probably multiple) operations; and while thread A is doing his operations, thread B shouldn't be doing anything - because you want to make sure that B only sees the "complete set" of updates made by A.

Sure, when that operation would be just about writing to one int for example, you could be using AtomicInteger for example. But when you are talking about several operations ... you need something else.

A "brute force" solution would be to add some sort of locking. Meaning: your threads share some LOCK object; and whenever one thread enters a "critical section" ... it needs to acquire that LOCK first (and of course release directly afterwards). But this will need very careful designing; as want to make sure that thread A isn't "starving" B by holding that lock for too long.

Looking at your code again, more closely ... maybe you could try to make your minPriority to be an AtomicInteger; the question is how that would relate to the other thread that is working the "size" of your queue.